# How can import SSL certificate at JVM

Tags: java, ssl

I must to call a web service with soap client.

So in eclipse I have create a new Project, import local WSDL, then I have do, right click on WSDL, Web Services, Generate Client.

So this process works, and then this, I have starting the server, and try to invoke some method. But I have this error

> Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target Message: ; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Now I know, that the problem is on the import of the certificate. So I'm export SSL certificate from https, and I have use this command to add the certificate at keystore

```
keytool -import -keystore keystore_healthnetbr.jks -alias alias -v -file edottotest.it
```

this command works, but after this, if I try to execute another call a have the error.

Comment: Try that code passing host:port to it. https://gist.github.com/philipsorst/4380376

Comment: what are the imput parameter?